# Able to vote on comments for a deleted question

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-voting, deleted-posts

I'm able to vote on comments to [deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469445/programmers-last-words/469460#469460) on [deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469445).

The proof, as they say, is in the pudding:
[image: before vote]

[image: after vote]

I did this multiple times in this post, in fact the "4" with the upvote is another one I just did in the post, but I had forgotten to take a screenshot before I did it.  I also made a view upvotes for other comments in this post today (even though it's been deleted for a while).

It's important to note that I can seem to upvote comments for other deleted answers (that are on deleted questions), but not the comments on the questions.

To reproduce that it actually 'took', I also cleared my cache and opened it on another browser.

Comment: This would seem to be by-design, based on the fact that the comments aren't locked the way questions are. The fact that only 10k'ers should see them in the first place would indicate to me that it would be obvious that voting for the comment wouldn't be very useful, but there's no reason to think a 10k'er wouldn't want to upvote a comment even after a question was deleted (I'm thinking MSO purposes but any site is basically the same as any other). I think this is more code than it would be worth to prevent, unless they just blocked comment upvoting on deleted questions on pageload. However...

Comment: However, aren't comment votes and flags handled by the same system? Wouldn't you want to be able to flag a comment even after a question was deleted? That seems to me to be a stumbling block from making a system-wide impact. Just my $0.05

Comment: I noticed this a while ago... you can flag them as well. I kinda like the behaviour actually.

Comment: @Jon Seigel +1, I sort of like it as well, it just seems inconsistent with the behavior for other deleted items.  As long as they don't take the the votes in deleted into account when doing badges, I don't really mind.

Comment: Yeah, it really caught me off guard when I discovered it (oh CRAP I didn't mean to upvote *that*). lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YOU WILL BE DENIED

<sub>after we do a build :)</sub>