# Comments on deleted answers can be voted on

Tags: bug, comments, voting, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Able to vote on comments for a deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73467/able-to-vote-on-comments-for-a-deleted-question)

I just cast a vote on a comment of a [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85892/collection-initialization-syntax-in-vb-2008/85958#85958) and it was apparently counted: there was no error message, and my vote is still displayed even after loading the page.

Is this intentional? If so, it’s odd. Voting no deleted answers (or questions) isn’t allowed, after all.

Comment: @Arjan: spoilsport. :-p